# Mariadb/docker error : Can't init tc log

Tags: mariadb, docker

I tried to dockerize MariaDB. It was running fine until it crashes and this is the log:

```
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.14-

MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.29-76.2 started; log sequence number 49590423178
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140090688898816 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2016-11-21 15:25:21 140091445393344 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I was thinking that it was a disk problem but no, I have 14G available.

Comment: I am encountering exactly the same issue as well when running MariaDB in docker

Answer (score 3):

I ended up deleting the tc.log file in /var/lib/mysql. When I started mysql again, it created a new tc.log and started up.

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mysql/tc.log
```

Comment: my server had filled up the disk and after adding some space mariadb didn't start any more. after 2h of search this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on Windows boot2docker? Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a proper solution to this - https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/38.

I 'fixed' this by emptying the host data directory (only do this if it's disposable and safe to do so!), using the `mariadb:10.0.20` image instead and `docker-compose up` again. A bit rubbish but it gets things up and running.

If anyone knows of a proper solution then let me know and I will edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: I face the same problem. I deleted all innodb and mariadb log files after that it is automatically started (I have setted restart to always)